# How to force inline divs inside another div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to make something like a slider on touch, scroll, or click. I need to force the divs to be `inline-block` — something like this:

```html
<div style="width: 100vw; overflow: hidden; overflow-x: auto;">
 <div class="sliderItem"></div>
 <div class="sliderItem"></div>
 <div class="sliderItem"></div>
 <div class="sliderItem"></div>
 <div class="sliderItem"></div>
 <div class="sliderItem"></div>
 <div class="sliderItem"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.sliderItem{
 width: 25%;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 background: red;
}
```

I am using bootstrap, even though I don't like it, because I have to. I didn't see anything in the code that would make the divs inside `float: left`. I mean, they go under one another when they can't fit all in a row. I want them all in one line so that the div becomes x-scrollable.

I am using `.row > .col-md-12` from Bootstrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`white-space: nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) on the parent.

Here's a working demo ([view on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/lesaket/edit?html,css,output)):

```css
.slider {
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sliderItem {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="sliderItem"></div>
  <div class="sliderItem"></div>
  <div class="sliderItem"></div>
  <div class="sliderItem"></div>
  <div class="sliderItem"></div>
  <div class="sliderItem"></div>
  <div class="sliderItem"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying it in divs but not parent my bad anyway I accepted it and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flex` on the parent and it will keep everything in a row.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.sliderItem {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background: red;
  height: 1em;
}

.sliderItem:nth-child(odd) {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="sliderItem"></div>
  <div class="sliderItem"></div>
  <div class="sliderItem"></div>
  <div class="sliderItem"></div>
  <div class="sliderItem"></div>
  <div class="sliderItem"></div>
  <div class="sliderItem"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is very good but "white-space: nowrap" from down below is much more simpler... Thanks anyway

Comment: @NoNameIamLame you're welcome but for what it's worth, that also applies the white space change to the contents of the `.sliderItem` elements, too. Assuming you don't want that, which I'm guessing you don't, you have to reset that in the individual `.sliderItem`s, which is unnecessary code when `flex` does this already. I would also argue that `white-space` is more for text, and `flex` is more for page layout/grid UI, which is what you're making.

Comment: "Damn this tagging don't work", anyway thanks for the explanation but why I shouldn't use this and I should flex even if it is made for text? What are differences between those? Inside divs which are inline I will have image and on click to pop up big image nothing else..

Comment: @NoNameIamLame they're apples and oranges. `Flex` is for organizing elements in the UI, creating grids/rows/columns/etc. `white-space` is for handling the space between inline things, which is traditionally to keep text from breaking/wrapping. But say you add text to the divs with an image, like the image has a caption or something, your text won't wrap unless you undo that on the individual divs. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmJbdG Use whatever you want, but `white-space` has the caveat I just mentioned, `flex` doesn't, and both of them work... soo....